# Grey-box parameter estimation with GEKKO (@error: Insufficient Model)

Tags: python, gekko

I am using GEKKO to estimate the parameters of a thermal storage tank. I divided the tank into 20 isothermal layers and have written the energy balance for each. The unknown parameters are the thermal conductivity between adjancent layers and the thermal loss coefficient to the environment. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

df = pd.read_csv('./dataset/charge_2.csv')

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()

# Parameters
rho = m.Const(1000) # density of water [kg/m^3]
r = m.Const(0.6) # inner radius of the tank
Ac = m.Const(np.pi*(r.value*r.value)) # cross-sectional area of tank [m^2]
Cp = m.Const(4186) # specific heat capacity of water [J/(kg.K)]
H = m.Const(1.79) # height of the tank [m]
w = m.Const(H.value/20) # Width of each layer [m]
M = m.Const(rho.value*Ac.value*w.value) # mass of each layer [kg]
As = m.Const(2*np.pi*r.value*w.value) # surface area of each layer
Dt = m.Const(60) # Sample time [sec]

N = len(df.mass_flowrate_charge.values) # Number of time steps

# Inputs
m_dot = m.Array(m.Param, N)  # mass flow rate [kg/s]
T_in = m.Array(m.Param, N)  # inlet temperature [deg C]
Tamb_top = m.Array(m.Param, N) # ambient temperature at top [deg C]
Tamb_mid = m.Array(m.Param, N)  # ambient temperature at mid [deg C]
Tamb_bot = m.Array(m.Param, N)  # ambient temperature at bottom [deg C]
for i in range(N):
    m_dot[i].value = df.mass_flowrate_charge.values[i]
    T_in[i].value = df.Tin_charge.values[i]
    Tamb_top[i].value = df.Tamb_top.values[i]
    Tamb_bot[i].value = df.Tamb_bot.values[i]
    Tamb_mid[i].value = df.Tamb_mid.values[i]

# Observations
T_out = m.Array(m.Param, N) # outlet temperature [deg C]
T_top = m.Array(m.Param, N) # top sensor temperature [deg C]
T_mid = m.Array(m.Param, N) # mid sensor temperature [deg C]
T_bot = m.Array(m.Param, N) # bottom sensor temperature [deg C]
for i in range(N):
    T_out[i].value = df.Tout_charge.values[i]
    T_top[i].value = df.Ttop_m.values[i]
    T_mid[i].value = df.Tmid_m.values[i]
    T_bot[i].value = df.Tbot_m.values[i]

# Initial temperature for all layers
T0 = T_top[0].value
   
# Initialize arrays to store results (temperature of layers)
T_L1, T_L2, T_L3, T_L4, T_L5,  T_L6, T_L7, T_L8, T_L9, T_L10,\
T_L11, T_L12, T_L13, T_L14, T_L15,  T_L16, T_L17, T_L18, T_L19, T_L20\
= m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), \
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1),\
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1),\
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1),\
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1),\
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1),\
  m.Array(m.Var, N+1), m.Array(m.Var, N+1)
                                           
# Set initial conditions
T_L1[0].value, T_L2[0].value, T_L3[0].value, T_L4[0].value, T_L5[0].value,\
T_L6[0].value, T_L7[0].value, T_L8[0].value, T_L9[0].value, T_L10[0].value,\
T_L11[0].value, T_L12[0].value, T_L13[0].value, T_L14[0].value, T_L15[0].value,\
T_L16[0].value, T_L17[0].value, T_L18[0].value, T_L19[0].value, T_L20[0].value\
= T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0, T0

# Identifiable parameters
# k_{i,i+1} = thermal conductivity between layer i and i+1 [W/(m.K)]. ka - thermal 
# coefficient  of tank [W/m2]
k_12, k_23, k_34, k_45, k_56, k_67, k_78, k_89, k_910, k_1011, k_1112, k_1213,\
k_1314, k_1415, k_1516, k_1617, k_1718, k_1819, k_1920, ka = \
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100),\
m.Var(0.6, lb = 0, ub = 100), m.Var(5, lb = 0, ub = 100)\
           
# Solve system of equations using Euler's method 
for n in range(N):

    # Energy Balance for each layer (conduction between layer + thermal losses
    # to environment + heat transfer due to fluid flow in layers)
    
    dT_L1_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_12*Ac)/w*(T_L2[n] - T_L1[n]) 
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L1[n])*(As+Ac)
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L2_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_12*Ac)/w*(T_L1[n] - T_L2[n]) + (k_23*Ac)/w*(T_L3[n] - T_L2[n]) 
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L2[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L3_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_23*Ac)/w*(T_L2[n] - T_L3[n]) + (k_34*Ac)/w*(T_L4[n] - T_L3[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_in[n] - T_L3[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L3[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L4_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_34*Ac)/w*(T_L3[n] - T_L4[n]) + (k_45*Ac)/w*(T_L5[n] - T_L4[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L3[n] - T_L4[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L4[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L5_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_45*Ac)/w*(T_L4[n] - T_L5[n]) + (k_56*Ac)/w*(T_L6[n] - T_L5[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L4[n] - T_L5[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L5[n])
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L6_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_56*Ac)/w*(T_L5[n] - T_L6[n]) + (k_67*Ac)/w*(T_L7[n] - T_L6[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L5[n] - T_L6[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L6[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L7_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_67*Ac)/w*(T_L6[n] - T_L7[n]) + (k_78*Ac)/w*(T_L8[n] - T_L7[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L6[n] - T_L7[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_top[n] - T_L7[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
        
    dT_L8_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_78*Ac)/w*(T_L7[n] - T_L8[n]) + (k_89*Ac)/w*(T_L9[n] - T_L8[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L7[n] - T_L8[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L8[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L9_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_89*Ac)/w*(T_L8[n] - T_L9[n]) + (k_910*Ac)/w*(T_L10[n] - T_L9[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L8[n] - T_L9[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L9[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L10_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_910*Ac)/w*(T_L9[n] - T_L10[n]) + (k_1011*Ac)/w*(T_L11[n] - T_L10[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L9[n] - T_L10[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L10[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L11_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1011*Ac)/w*(T_L10[n] - T_L11[n]) + (k_1112*Ac)/w*(T_L12[n] - T_L11[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L10[n] - T_L11[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L11[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L12_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1112*Ac)/w*(T_L11[n] - T_L12[n]) + (k_1213*Ac)/w*(T_L13[n] - T_L12[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L11[n] - T_L12[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L12[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L13_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1213*Ac)/w*(T_L12[n] - T_L13[n]) + (k_1314*Ac)/w*(T_L14[n] - T_L13[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L12[n] - T_L13[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_mid[n] - T_L13[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L14_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1314*Ac)/w*(T_L13[n] - T_L14[n]) + (k_1415*Ac)/w*(T_L15[n] - T_L14[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L13[n] - T_L14[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L14[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L15_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1415*Ac)/w*(T_L14[n] - T_L15[n]) + (k_1516*Ac)/w*(T_L16[n] - T_L15[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L14[n] - T_L15[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L15[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L16_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1516*Ac)/w*(T_L15[n] - T_L16[n]) + (k_1617*Ac)/w*(T_L17[n] - T_L16[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L15[n] - T_L16[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L16[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L17_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1617*Ac)/w*(T_L16[n] - T_L17[n]) + (k_1718*Ac)/w*(T_L18[n] - T_L17[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L16[n] - T_L17[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L17[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L18_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1718*Ac)/w*(T_L17[n] - T_L18[n]) + (k_1819*Ac)/w*(T_L19[n] - T_L18[n])
                + m_dot[n]*Cp*(T_L17[n] - T_L18[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L18[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    dT_L19_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1819*Ac)/w*(T_L18[n] - T_L19[n]) + (k_1920*Ac)/w*(T_L20[n] - T_L19[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L19[n])*As
                )/(M*Cp))
        
    dT_L20_dt = m.Intermediate(((k_1920*Ac)/w*(T_L19[n] - T_L20[n])
                + ka*(Tamb_bot[n] - T_L20[n])*(As+Ac)
                )/(M*Cp))
    
    
    T_L1[n+1] == T_L1[n] + Dt*dT_L1_dt,
    T_L2[n+1] == T_L2[n] + Dt*dT_L2_dt,
    T_L3[n+1] == T_L3[n] + Dt*dT_L3_dt,
    T_L4[n+1] == T_L4[n] + Dt*dT_L4_dt,
    T_L5[n+1] == T_L5[n] + Dt*dT_L5_dt,
    T_L6[n+1] == T_L6[n] + Dt*dT_L6_dt,
    T_L7[n+1] == T_L7[n] + Dt*dT_L7_dt,
    T_L8[n+1] == T_L8[n] + Dt*dT_L8_dt,
    T_L9[n+1] == T_L9[n] + Dt*dT_L9_dt,
    T_L10[n+1] == T_L10[n] + Dt*dT_L10_dt,
    T_L11[n+1] == T_L11[n] + Dt*dT_L11_dt,
    T_L12[n+1] == T_L12[n] + Dt*dT_L12_dt,
    T_L13[n+1] == T_L13[n] + Dt*dT_L13_dt,
    T_L14[n+1] == T_L14[n] + Dt*dT_L14_dt,
    T_L15[n+1] == T_L15[n] + Dt*dT_L15_dt,
    T_L16[n+1] == T_L16[n] + Dt*dT_L16_dt,
    T_L17[n+1] == T_L17[n] + Dt*dT_L17_dt,
    T_L18[n+1] == T_L18[n] + Dt*dT_L18_dt,
    T_L19[n+1] == T_L19[n] + Dt*dT_L19_dt,
    T_L20[n+1] == T_L20[n] + Dt*dT_L20_dt
        
        
error_top = m.sum((T_top - T_L5[:-1]) ** 2) # Top sensor error
error_mid = m.sum((T_mid - T_L11[:-1]) ** 2) # Mid sensor error
error_bot = m.sum((T_bot - T_L16[:-1]) ** 2) # Bottom sensor error
error_out = m.sum((T_out - T_L18[:-1]) ** 2) # Outlet sensor error

error = error_top + error_mid + error_bot + error_out

m.Minimize(error)

m.solve()
```

I get the following error:

```
apm 62.18.232.57_gk_model12 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :            0
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            0
   Residuals    :            0
 
 
 @error: Insufficient Model
 Model must contain at least 1 variable and 1 equation
 STOPPING...
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "xxxx.py", line 214, in <module>
    m.solve()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2185, in solve
    raise Exception(response)

Exception:  @error: Insufficient Model
 Model must contain at least 1 variable and 1 equation
 STOPPING...
```

I will appreciate if someone could help me here. I have uploaded the dataset file required to run the code at https://github.com/nagpalh/temporary/blob/main/charge_2.csv

I checked the .apm file also, it shows the Variables, Intermediates, Connections and Equations noramlly.

Answer (score 1):

Great application of Gekko! Try using `IMODE=5` with [Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation) instead of `IMODE=3` where you used the [Euler's method](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonDynamicSim) for integration. The objective may need to be modified. Should the ambient temperature at the 4 levels match the thermal storage tank temperatures? It seems like it should be using the measured temperatures of the water at the 4 levels. The ambient temperature at the 4 levels should be an input to the model to control the heat transfer.

[image: Regression results]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nagpalh/temporary/main/charge_2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()

# Parameters
rho = 1000 # density of water [kg/m^3]
r = 0.6 # inner radius of the tank
Ac = np.pi*(r*r) # cross-sectional area of tank [m^2]
Cp = 4186 # specific heat capacity of water [J/(kg.K)]
H = 1.79 # height of the tank [m]
w = H/20 # Width of each layer [m]
M = rho*Ac*w # mass of each layer [kg]
As = 2*np.pi*r*w # surface area of each layer
Dt = 60 # Sample time [sec]

# Inputs
m_dot = m.Param()  # mass flow rate [kg/s]
T_in = m.Param()  # inlet temperature [deg C]
Tamb_top = m.Param() # ambient temperature at top [deg C]
Tamb_mid = m.Param()  # ambient temperature at mid [deg C]
Tamb_bot = m.Param()  # ambient temperature at bottom [deg C]
m_dot.value = df.mass_flowrate_charge.values
T_in.value = df.Tin_charge.values
Tamb_top.value = df.Tamb_top.values
Tamb_bot.value = df.Tamb_bot.values
Tamb_mid.value = df.Tamb_mid.values

# Observations
T_out = m.Param() # outlet temperature [deg C]
T_top = m.Param() # top sensor temperature [deg C]
T_mid = m.Param() # mid sensor temperature [deg C]
T_bot = m.Param() # bottom sensor temperature [deg C]
T_out.value = df.Tout_charge.values
T_top.value = df.Ttop_m.values
T_mid.value = df.Tmid_m.values
T_bot.value = df.Tbot_m.values

# Initial temperature for all layers
T0 = df.Ttop_m.values
   
# Initialize arrays to store results (temperature of layers)
T_L1, T_L2, T_L3, T_L4, T_L5,  T_L6, T_L7, T_L8, T_L9, T_L10,\
T_L11, T_L12, T_L13, T_L14, T_L15,  T_L16, T_L17, T_L18, T_L19, T_L20\
= m.Array(m.Var, 20,value=T0[0])
                                           
# Identifiable parameters
# k_{i,i+1} = thermal conductivity between layer i and i+1 [W/(m.K)]. ka - thermal 
# coefficient  of tank [W/m2]
ka = m.FV(5,lb=0,ub=10000)
p = m.Array(m.FV,19,lb=0.6,ub=10000)
k_12, k_23, k_34, k_45, k_56, k_67, k_78, k_89, k_910, k_1011, k_1112, k_1213,\
k_1314, k_1415, k_1516, k_1617, k_1718, k_1819, k_1920 = p

# Solve system of equations 

# Energy Balance for each layer (conduction between layer + thermal losses
# to environment + heat transfer due to fluid flow in layers)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L1.dt() == (k_12*Ac)/w*(T_L2 - T_L1) 
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L1)*(As+Ac))

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L2.dt() == (k_12*Ac)/w*(T_L1 - T_L2) + (k_23*Ac)/w*(T_L3 - T_L2) 
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L2)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L3.dt() == (k_23*Ac)/w*(T_L2 - T_L3) + (k_34*Ac)/w*(T_L4 - T_L3)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_in - T_L3)
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L3)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L4.dt() == (k_34*Ac)/w*(T_L3 - T_L4) + (k_45*Ac)/w*(T_L5 - T_L4)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L3 - T_L4)
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L4)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L5.dt() == (k_45*Ac)/w*(T_L4 - T_L5) + (k_56*Ac)/w*(T_L6 - T_L5)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L4 - T_L5)
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L5))

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L6.dt() == (k_56*Ac)/w*(T_L5 - T_L6) + (k_67*Ac)/w*(T_L7 - T_L6)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L5 - T_L6)
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L6)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L7.dt() == (k_67*Ac)/w*(T_L6 - T_L7) + (k_78*Ac)/w*(T_L8 - T_L7)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L6 - T_L7)
            + ka*(Tamb_top - T_L7)*As)
    
m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L8.dt() == (k_78*Ac)/w*(T_L7 - T_L8) + (k_89*Ac)/w*(T_L9 - T_L8)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L7 - T_L8)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L8)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L9.dt() == (k_89*Ac)/w*(T_L8 - T_L9) + (k_910*Ac)/w*(T_L10 - T_L9)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L8 - T_L9)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L9)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L10.dt() == (k_910*Ac)/w*(T_L9 - T_L10) + (k_1011*Ac)/w*(T_L11 - T_L10)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L9 - T_L10)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L10)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L11.dt() == (k_1011*Ac)/w*(T_L10 - T_L11) + (k_1112*Ac)/w*(T_L12 - T_L11)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L10 - T_L11)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L11)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L12.dt() == (k_1112*Ac)/w*(T_L11 - T_L12) + (k_1213*Ac)/w*(T_L13 - T_L12)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L11 - T_L12)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L12)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L13.dt() == (k_1213*Ac)/w*(T_L12 - T_L13) + (k_1314*Ac)/w*(T_L14 - T_L13)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L12 - T_L13)
            + ka*(Tamb_mid - T_L13)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L14.dt() == (k_1314*Ac)/w*(T_L13 - T_L14) + (k_1415*Ac)/w*(T_L15 - T_L14)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L13 - T_L14)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L14)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L15.dt() == (k_1415*Ac)/w*(T_L14 - T_L15) + (k_1516*Ac)/w*(T_L16 - T_L15)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L14 - T_L15)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L15)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L16.dt() == (k_1516*Ac)/w*(T_L15 - T_L16) + (k_1617*Ac)/w*(T_L17 - T_L16)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L15 - T_L16)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L16)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L17.dt() == (k_1617*Ac)/w*(T_L16 - T_L17) + (k_1718*Ac)/w*(T_L18 - T_L17)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L16 - T_L17)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L17)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L18.dt() == (k_1718*Ac)/w*(T_L17 - T_L18) + (k_1819*Ac)/w*(T_L19 - T_L18)
            + m_dot*Cp*(T_L17 - T_L18)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L18)*As)

m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L19.dt() == (k_1819*Ac)/w*(T_L18 - T_L19) + (k_1920*Ac)/w*(T_L20 - T_L19)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L19)*As)
    
m.Equation(M*Cp*T_L20.dt() == (k_1920*Ac)/w*(T_L19 - T_L20)
            + ka*(Tamb_bot - T_L20)*(As+Ac))
        
m.Minimize((T_top - T_L5) ** 2)  # Top sensor error
m.Minimize((T_mid - T_L11) ** 2) # Mid sensor error
m.Minimize((T_bot - T_L16) ** 2) # Bottom sensor error
m.Minimize((T_out - T_L18) ** 2) # Outlet sensor error

m.options.IMODE=5
m.time = np.arange(0,len(df))
m.solve()

# open degress of freedom
ka.STATUS = 1
for pi in p:
    pi.STATUS = 1
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.solve()

# print parameters
print(f'ka: {ka.value[0]}')
for i,pi in enumerate(p):
    print(f'p[{i}]: {pi.value[0]}')

# create plots
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L1)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L2)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L3)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L4)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L5)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L6)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L7)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L8)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L9)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L10)
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L11)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L12)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L13)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L14)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L15)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L16)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L17)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L18)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L19)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L20)

# create plots
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L5,'b-',label='T_L5')
plt.plot(m.time,T_top,'rx',label='T_top')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L11,'b-',label='T_L11')
plt.plot(m.time,T_mid,'rx',label='T_mid')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L16,'b-',label='T_L16')
plt.plot(m.time,T_bot,'rx',label='T_bot')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(m.time,T_L18,'b-',label='T_L18')
plt.plot(m.time,T_out,'rx',label='T_out')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The ambient temperature at the 4 levels Tamb_top, Tamb_mid, Tamb_bot are inputs to the model as they are measured. The objective is to minimize the error (measurement vs simulation) at the 4 levels. 

I tried writing my own Python function that models the tank behaviour at the 20 layers (keeping the Euler's discretization). Then, I used scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize the objective mentioned above. It works pretty good; however, I wanted to check with Gekko.  Not sure, how to proceed.

Comment: There are additional tutorials here: https://apmonitor.com/do If it is working in Scipy then I recommend that you keep using that. The problem with the code above is that the difference between the measured ambient temperature and water temperature should not be the objective function. It should be the measured water temperature and the predictive water temperature, if you have the measured water values available.

Comment: I think there might be a slight misunderstanding. The objective function uses the measured (`T_top`, `T_bot`, and `T_mid`) as you mentioned, not the measured ambient temperature (`Tamb_top`, `Tamb_bot`, and `Tamb_mid`). Scipy works fine for me; however, I would prefer to use Gekko for my future projects.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that explanation. I see how you did it correctly. Nice work on the application!